# Best approach to display the grid view in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I am new to SharePoint and I'm looking on how to display data to UI from data table. However I used ASP.NET GridView but I didn't got the look and feel of SharePoint list control.

Is there any control in SharePoint that gives the look and feel of SharePoint list control and display the data?

My Code that I tried :

```
public GridView GridView1 = new GridView();

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { 
                        new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Checked", typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
            /*GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            this.Controls.Add(GridView1);*/


            TemplateField customField1 = new TemplateField();
            customField1.ShowHeader = true;
            customField1.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "Fieldname", "", "");
            customField1.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "", "Checked", "RadioButton");
            //GridView1.Columns.Add(customField1);


            GridView1.DataSource = dt; // GetData();    //function to return a DataSource
            GridView1.DataBind();
            this.Controls.Add(GridView1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a SharePoint control called SPGridView that you can use to mimic the SharePoint lists look and feel.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx?s=6

Here is a sample:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16

Comment: In my case I don't have the UI. I need to develop sp grid view dynamically on run time by implementing ITemplate interface. Is it possible?

Comment: What you mean with 'don't have UI' ? You can use the SPGridView control in any type of C# code as long as it is executed / hosted on a SharePoint machine.  (you need access to the SharePoint dll's).

Comment: I mean to say I can't decide what type of the columns my grid can have. I will get to know the type of the gridview column at run time and need to design the template field based on the type it could be - hyperlink, Drop down  etc...  In the link that you have given grid is designed at compile time. However I want to get this done at run time. So I guess even that is possible. isn't it?

Comment: Yes you can add columns dynamically see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/adding-checkboxes-in-sharepoint-gridview-spgridview/  or here http://nishantrana.me/2009/03/23/using-spgridview-to-bound-to-list-data-in-sharepoint/